# load xml into dataset with column filtering

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

i would like to load xml into dataset with only 2 columns (name, price)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<file>
<record>
    <name>A</name>
    <address>B</address>
    <date>12-12-2010</date>
    <price>100</price>
</record>
<record>
    <name>B</name>
    <address>C</address>
    <date>01-01-1999</date>
    <price>23</price>
</record>
</file>
```

here is my c# code:

```
string myXMLfile = "C:\\asdf.xml";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds.ReadXml(myXMLfile);

dataGrid1.DataSource = ds;
dataGrid1.DataMember = "record";
```

that displays all of the records. what can i do to filter the data?

filter dataset/dataview/datatable

or read specific xml elements and load them into dataset ?

or filtering datagrdview?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set your [`dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) to false.
2. Display only required columns.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. it is dataGrid in win form

Answer (score 0):

How about using LINQ to XML to read from the XML [`XElement.Load(@"C:\asdf.xml");`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.load.aspx)
Then using LINQ to filter the results and call a ToList...  Why do you need to use a dataset?

Comment: that's a good idea
can i bind datasource = results.Tolist();
?

Comment: yes, datasource can be a list.  Using a dataset to contain the data seems a bit OTT.