# Load XmlFile into Sql-server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I'm looking to load my XmlFile to Sql-Server, i'll use sqlbulkcopy, but i don't know how to convert my XmlFile to DataSet, because they are a lot of imbriqued table. Here's my XmlFile and thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
<data>
<created_time>2016-09-23T22:37:33+01:00</created_time>
<id>12451</id>    
<message>Cool</message>
<from>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>user1</name>
  <picture>
    <data>
      <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
      <url>https://server.com/pic.jpg</url>
    </data>
  </picture>
</from>
<comments>
  <data>
    <created_time>2016-09-23T22:46:59+01:00</created_time>     
    <id>112</id>        
    <message>ok</message>
    <from>
      <id>1245</id>
      <name>reply user1</name>
      <picture>
        <data>
          <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
          <url>https://server.com/pic2.jpg</url>
        </data>
      </picture>
    </from>
  </data>
  <data>
    <created_time>2016-09-23T22:47:41+01:00</created_time>       
    <id>113</id>        
    <message>nice</message>
    <from>
      <id>1246</id>
      <name>reply user2</name>
      <picture>
        <data>
          <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
          <url>https://server.com/pic3.jpg</url>
        </data>
      </picture>
    </from>
  </data>      
  <paging>
    <cursors>
      <before>sdfdfdsfdfdsfdsf</before>
      <after>dsfdsfdfsfdffdfdf</after>
    </cursors>
  </paging>
</comments>
</data>
<data>
<created_time>2016-09-23T22:35:20+01:00</created_time>    
<id>47854</id>    
<message>Thank you</message>
<from>
  <id>365</id>
  <name>user2</name>
  <picture>
    <data>
      <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
      <url>https://server.com/pic4.jpg</url>
    </data>
  </picture>
</from>
<comments>      
  <data>
    <created_time>2016-09-23T22:47:05+01:00</created_time>
    <id>1285</id>        
    <message>what?</message>
    <from>
      <id>33</id>
      <name>reply user1</name>
      <picture>
        <data>
          <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
          <url>https://server.com/pic5.jpg</url>
        </data>
      </picture>
    </from>
  </data>
  <data>
    <created_time>2016-09-23T22:55:54+01:00</created_time>
    <id>1982</id>        
    <message>No.</message>
    <from>
      <id>102</id>
      <name>reply user2</name>
      <picture>
        <data>
          <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
          <url>https://server.com/pic6.jpg</url>
        </data>
      </picture>
    </from>
   </data>      
  </comments>
 </data>    
</data>
```

Comment: Have you tried the simple approach (ds.ReadXml(myXMLfile);) as described in the question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3491347/6741942 I think DataSet automatically determines the schema.

Comment: using (ds.ReadXml(myXMLfile); give me error "The same table (data) cannot be the child table in two nested relations".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's OK, the solution is to load XmlFile to MS-SQL server. In my C# program i use this command :

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Table_fileXml(xml) SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn From OPENROWSET(BULK 'd:\\XmlFile.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS X";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

And finally create a trigger that will execute a stored procedure after that my file XmlFile will be inserted to my MS-SQL Server Database :

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger1]
ON  [dbo].[Table_FileXml] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for trigger here

DECLARE @xml xml
SELECT top(1) @xml=xml FROM Table_fileXml ORDER BY id DESC

SELECT data.value('created_time[1]','datetime') AS Data_CreatedTime
  ,data.value('id[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Data_Id
  ,data.value('message[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Data_Message
  ,data.value('(from/id)[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS Data_From_Id
  --more values here
  ,data.value('(from/picture/data/url)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Data_From_Picture_URL
  --more values here

  ,comment.value('created_time[1]','datetime') AS Comment_CreatedTime
  ,comment.value('id[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Comment_Id
  ,comment.value('message[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Comment_Message
  ,comment.value('(from/id)[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS Comment_From_Id
  --more values here
  ,comment.value('(from/picture/data/url)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Comment_From_Picture_URL
  --more values here

FROM @xml.nodes('/data/data') AS A(data)
OUTER APPLY data.nodes('comments/data') AS B(comment) 
BEGIN
DECLARE @xml2 xml
SELECT top(1) @xml2=xml FROM Table_fileXml ORDER BY id DESC
INSERT INTO Table_comment(from_id,from_pic,comment_message)
SELECT DISTINCT comment.value('(from/id)[1]','nvarchar(50)')  AS from_id,
data.value('(from/picture/data/url)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS from_pic,
comment.value('message[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS comment_message
FROM @xml2.nodes('/data/data') AS A(data)
OUTER APPLY data.nodes('comments/data') AS B(comment) 
END
END
```

And the result is correct. Using just trigger without stored procedure give me just the last row from my FileXML. It's why I must use stored procedure with trigger.

Thank you "Shnugo", "Martin Staufcik" and "Abouzar" for your precious help.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use SSIS or read xml in sql server for more information:
[Importing and Processing data from XML files into SQL Server tables](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/)

[sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/)

Comment: I want to store data into separe columns, i don't want to use "OpenXml"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database column of type `varbinary(max)` which will map to a `byte[]` property in your domain model. Then store the XML document into this column using a `XmlWriter`.

```
public virtual void Save(
    XmlWriter w
)
```

Comment: I want to shred Xml File and store attributes and elements in separate columns. "Data" into one table and "comments" into a second table.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the element `data` is used both on the root level and also inside comments node. You could rename one of them and then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

With the following query you'll get all data out of your XML in a derived tabel.

It should be easy to insert this into appropriate tables. Hints:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
SELECT col1, col2 INTO #tbl ...
INSERT INTO tbl SELECT col1, col2, ...
```

And for the creation of IDs you might use something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` with the fitting `PARTITION BY`...

Your XML

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
<data>
<created_time>2016-09-23T22:37:33+01:00</created_time>
<id>12451</id>    
<message>Cool</message>
<from>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>user1</name>
  <picture>
    <data>
      <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
      <url>https://server.com/pic.jpg</url>
    </data>
  </picture>
</from>
<comments>
  <data>
    <created_time>2016-09-23T22:46:59+01:00</created_time>     
    <id>112</id>        
    <message>ok</message>
    <from>
      <id>1245</id>
      <name>reply user1</name>
      <picture>
        <data>
          <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
          <url>https://server.com/pic2.jpg</url>
        </data>
      </picture>
    </from>
  </data>
  <data>
    <created_time>2016-09-23T22:47:41+01:00</created_time>       
    <id>113</id>        
    <message>nice</message>
    <from>
      <id>1246</id>
      <name>reply user2</name>
      <picture>
        <data>
          <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
          <url>https://server.com/pic3.jpg</url>
        </data>
      </picture>
    </from>
  </data>      
  <paging>
    <cursors>
      <before>sdfdfdsfdfdsfdsf</before>
      <after>dsfdsfdfsfdffdfdf</after>
    </cursors>
  </paging>
</comments>
</data>
<data>
<created_time>2016-09-23T22:35:20+01:00</created_time>    
<id>47854</id>    
<message>Thank you</message>
<from>
  <id>365</id>
  <name>user2</name>
  <picture>
    <data>
      <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
      <url>https://server.com/pic4.jpg</url>
    </data>
  </picture>
</from>
<comments>      
  <data>
    <created_time>2016-09-23T22:47:05+01:00</created_time>
    <id>1285</id>        
    <message>what?</message>
    <from>
      <id>33</id>
      <name>reply user1</name>
      <picture>
        <data>
          <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
          <url>https://server.com/pic5.jpg</url>
        </data>
      </picture>
    </from>
  </data>
  <data>
    <created_time>2016-09-23T22:55:54+01:00</created_time>
    <id>1982</id>        
    <message>No.</message>
    <from>
      <id>102</id>
      <name>reply user2</name>
      <picture>
        <data>
          <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
          <url>https://server.com/pic6.jpg</url>
        </data>
      </picture>
    </from>
   </data>      
  </comments>
 </data>    
</data>';
```

The query

```
SELECT data.value('created_time[1]','datetime') AS Data_CreatedTime
      ,data.value('id[1]','int') AS Data_Id
      ,data.value('message[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Data_Message
      ,data.value('(from/id)[1]','int') AS Data_From_Id
      --more values here
      ,data.value('(from/picture/data/url)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Data_From_Picture_URL
      --more values here

      ,comment.value('created_time[1]','datetime') AS Comment_CreatedTime
      ,comment.value('id[1]','int') AS Comment_Id
      ,comment.value('message[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Comment_Message
      ,comment.value('(from/id)[1]','int') AS Comment_From_Id
      --more values here
      ,comment.value('(from/picture/data/url)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Comment_From_Picture_URL
      --more values here
FROM @xml.nodes('/data/data') AS A(data)
OUTER APPLY data.nodes('comments/data') AS B(comment)
```

The result

```
+-------------------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| Data_CreatedTime        | Data_Id | Data_Message | Data_From_Id | Data_From_Picture_URL       | Comment_CreatedTime     | Comment_Id | Comment_Message | Comment_From_Id | Comment_From_Picture_URL    |
+-------------------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| 2016-09-23 21:37:33.000 | 12451   | Cool         | 1            | https://server.com/pic.jpg  | 2016-09-23 21:46:59.000 | 112        | ok              | 1245            | https://server.com/pic2.jpg |
+-------------------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| 2016-09-23 21:37:33.000 | 12451   | Cool         | 1            | https://server.com/pic.jpg  | 2016-09-23 21:47:41.000 | 113        | nice            | 1246            | https://server.com/pic3.jpg |
+-------------------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| 2016-09-23 21:35:20.000 | 47854   | Thank you    | 365          | https://server.com/pic4.jpg | 2016-09-23 21:47:05.000 | 1285       | what?           | 33              | https://server.com/pic5.jpg |
+-------------------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| 2016-09-23 21:35:20.000 | 47854   | Thank you    | 365          | https://server.com/pic4.jpg | 2016-09-23 21:55:54.000 | 1982       | No.             | 102             | https://server.com/pic6.jpg |
+-------------------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
```